# How to get a list of subfolders and files in jfrog Artifactory

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory, jenkins-groovy

I am looking to fetch the subfolders and files inside jfrog artifactory repo and for that I am running the below script which I am running in Groovy

```
def test = sh(script: "curl -u uname:password -X POST -k https://artifactory.xxxx.com/artifactory/api/search/aql -d 'items.find({\"type\" : \"file\",\"\$or\":[{\"repo\" : {\"\$match\" : \"war*\"}, \"repo\" : {\"\$match\" : \"web*\"} }]}).include(\"name\",\"repo\",\"path\",\"size\").sort({\"\$desc\": [\"size\"]}).limit(10)'", returnStdout: true).trim()
echo "The list is ${test}"
```

But its not returning any value.
Any solution would be helpful.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `api/storage` get the children of a artifact path.

For example, your Artifactory has repository: `maven-prerelease-local` for maven, you can open
`https://artifactory.xxxx.com/maven-prerelease-local` in browser, it will list file and folders under it.

By adding `api/storage` in URL, it will return a JSON response.

```
def test = sh(script: """
  curl -u uname:password -X GET -k \
  "https://artifactory.xxxx.com/api/storage/maven-prerelease-local/com/xxx/xxx/"
""", returnStdout: true).trim()

echo "The list is ${test}"
```

Answer (score 0):

To get detailed information about the existing subfolders under a specific directory/repository, you can use the following format of execution.

```
$ jfrog rt search --spec=test.aql
[Info] Searching artifacts...
[Info] Found 1 artifact.
[
  {
    "path": "delta-generic-local/alpha/beta",
    "type": "folder",
    "created": "2022-08-04T13:53:36.173Z",
    "modified": "2022-08-04T13:53:36.173Z"
  }
]
```

& the spec file includes the following content.

```
$ cat test.aql
    {
      "files":
        [
          {
            "aql":
              {
                "items.find" :
                   {
                     "type":"folder",
                     "repo":{"$eq":"delta-generic-local"},
                     "path":{"$eq":"alpha"}
                   }
              }
          }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Script I am running in groovy.

Comment: I cant run JF command as jf isn't installed in my jenkins, I have to use Curl or wget command to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are in escape special character hell. Put your query in a *.aql file and then point to it. See below.

// Create the aql file and write the query to it

```
writeFile file: 'sizeQuery.aql', text: 'items.find({"type":"file"}).sort({"$desc":["size"]}).limit(10)'
```

// Pass the aql file to your curl command

```
sh 'curl -u uname:password -H "Content-Type: text/plain" -X POST -d @sizeQuery.aql "https://artifactory.xxxx.com/artifactory/api/search/aql"'
```