# Find the target java version for a dependency

Tags: java, maven, artifactory

Is there any way that I can know what is the target java version (../6/../8/../11/../17/..) for a maven dependency. I have all my dependencies in JFROG artifactory and would like to do it without downloading the dependency, if possible.

Thanks,
Himanshu

Comment: If you can run code on the Artifactory server, you can write a script to examine the dependency. I can't think of another way without downloading it.

Comment: Simple answer: No possbile. Reasons: A dependency which is written for JDK 8 could be used in JDK11+ but there could be dependencies which are multi release jars which could be used for JDK 8+ etc. and even JDK6 based deps coult be used in higher versions of Java... only verifiable via using it...

Answer (score 0):

[File Listing](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-rest-apis/file-list), against the respective Maven repository would help to achieve this requirement. You may also prefer using JFrog CLI with AQL, with the example I have shared [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73237422/12378094).